# Compilation error in Stored Procedure (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
create or replace function getAvg(id1 IN number, id2 IN number) return number as
sal1 number;
sal2 number;
avg number;
BEGIN
    select esal into sal1 from employees where eno = id1;
    select esal into sal2 from employees where eno = id2;
    avg := (sal1+sal2)/2;
    return avg;
END;
/
```

When I try to compile the above code, I get compilation errors with following message:

```
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
```

But when I replace `avg` after `return` with `(sal1+sal2)/2` it compiles successfully.

Comment: Because `avg` is one of the reserved keywords which are disallowed to be used.

Comment: As pointed out in both comments and answer, your problem issues from using a reserved/key word as an object name.  You can banish this problem forever, without ever having to refer to a list of reserved words, by simply implementing a sane, rational set of naming conventions.  I strongly advocate for naming all table columns in the format 'adjective_noun'.   This eliminates the potential use of a reserved word, and it makes your names for self documenting.  Add to that, pl/sql variables start with 'v_' prefix, and parms start with 'p_' prefix.  Problem solved.

Comment: By the way, it's a stored function, not a procedure. And it's written in PL/SQL, not SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's *bad habits*: never name your own objects, variables, whatever using reserved words or keywords. `avg` is a built-in function; rename the variable:

```
SQL> create or replace function getAvg(id1 IN number, id2 IN number)
  2    return number
  3  as
  4    sal1 number;
  5    sal2 number;
  6    l_avg number;
  7  BEGIN
  8      select esal into sal1 from employees where eno = id1;
  9      select esal into sal2 from employees where eno = id2;
 10      l_avg := (sal1+sal2)/2;
 11      return l_avg;
 12  END;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select * from employees;

       ENO       ESAL
---------- ----------
         1        100
         2        200

SQL> select getavg(1, 2) from dual;

GETAVG(1,2)
-----------
        150

SQL>
```